# spark scala insert overwrite hive is taking too longer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load spark dataframe into hive like below:

`df.repartition(col(col_nme)).write.mode("overwrite").format("ORC").option("compression","snappy").insertInto(hive_tbl)`

The same df in pyspark loads in 2 minutes but with scala it loads in 15 mins.

Any suggestions or clues?

Comment: are these repeated results ? to bench mark i mean. May be you havesome other jobs running at that time. In priniciple its not possible.

Comment: @ Ram Ghadiyaram . We are converting pyspark code to scala. We have a dedicated queue and there is no chance of some other jobs running.First we ran pysaprk code. Once it is done we triggered scala code and scala insert overwrite is taking too longer. We repeated the scenario trice and pysaprk finishes in 2 minutes and scala takes more than 15 minutes.

Comment: are you using queue in hadoop capacity scheduler ? if so if any other jobs are running in that queue it wont allow another job to be in running state. may thats the case for you

Comment: For sure no other jobs are running in the queue.This is the only job running in that queue.

Comment: may be something silly chcek meticulusly.